# Is there a more efficient route to finding severely old questions which have not had any activity?

Tags: discussion, review, vote-to-close

While trying to review some old questions just to clean up a bit I came across this post:

[Lost title on tabs of tabcontrol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2028343/lost-title-on-tabs-of-tabcontrol)

[image: Epic]

3 years, 0 votes, 0 answers, 61 views. Sure, it has 4 comments. Should there be a gold badge for a question with this type of wherewithal to stand the test of time without generating views, votes, nor answers? Clearly not, but what should be done about this aside from having to dig all the way down to the 4.75Mth question?

I was going to vote to close so it could go through the possible process of closing and deleting since it seems poorly written and clearly did not help anyone. It was hard to find this, as it has a vague title and won't show up on the active page.

I was on page roughly 95,000 of the questions (there are always new ones added so the page count tends to increase constantly). It seems like it would be very hard to find these if not browsing in this fashion. Although this approach feels inefficient to me, I cannot see another way around it at present.

Should community screen for these types of questions and introduce them into the close queue?

Should they also be flagged, or is a close vote enough from a single user perspective?

Comment: The Tumbleweed badge is seen as a consolation prize.  I've never heard of a gold consolation prize.

Comment: @psubsee2003 - Unsung Hero?

Comment: I don't see the point of awarding badges for hopelessly uninteresting questions.

Comment: @LBT Unsung Hero is slightly different as that is designed to reward people for participating is low traffic tags.  The is no reward in the Tumbleweed, it is just to say "So you asked a question no-one wanted to look at, have a cookie"

Comment: @TravisJ at this point, probably no saving this question.  You might want to just re-ask your real question and revert this to the original.  Your edit to change the question to what you really wanted to ask already attracted a downvote to your answerer.

Comment: When browsing to find this question, do you mean that you were looking at a list of all questions, or just [the ones that earned the Tumbleweed badge](http://stackoverflow.com/badges/63/tumbleweed)?

Comment: @GeorgeCummins - Of all questions. This question did not earn the Tumbleweed badge because it had a few comments when asked. 50 questions per page, page 95,000.. 50*95000 = 4,750,000 -ish

Comment: @psubsee2003 - That answer should be a comment. It did not address the question at the time and the edit does not affect that.

Comment: @TravisJ borderline, but it did answer the question in your title.  Delete the question if you want, but the revised question is a fair one and deserves discussion that is not buried in the results of your semi-joke of your original version.  That's why I suggested reasking it.

Comment: @psubsee2003 - I can vote to delete. But as it stands this question is answerable and may not actually be deleted. That it got downvotes for the original form is understandable and I am fine with that.

Answer (score 2):

As @psubsee2003 mentioned, the Tumbleweed badge is basically a 'no one took time to answer your question. Please don't cry' type of badge - do we *really* want users to have gold 'I asked a question no one took time to answer' badge?

Comment: *liked* might not be the best word to use here..

Comment: tldr I guess. For your answer in the form of a qustion: No, we don't. My title was a play on these poor old questions and clearly it should be reworded. Although Servy edited the "badge request" tag into the question this was more about dealing with old stale questions. I guess you answered the title, but not really the question, and I am going to edit the title.

Comment: @Seth That better?

Comment: That's somewhat better, though IMO if someone has an answer the chances that they'll post that answer are good. After all, we're talking about low *views* here (for the most port).. I think this has a lot to do with title.